# Can I run macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on iMac 11,2?

Tags: xcode, imac, macos-mojave

I have an iMac 11,2 mid-2010. Can I run macOS Mojave 10.13.6 because Apple released Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5 which requires macOS 10.13.6 Mojave? Currently I am on macOS High Sierra. Can I run macOS Mojave or can I install Xcode 10.2 on this system?

My iMac's system report:

[image: iMac system report]

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have your names & numbers confused.

Mojave is 10.14, currently at 10.14.4.
High Sierra is 10.13, currently at 10.13.6

Xcode 10.2 minimum spec is High Sierra, 10.13.6 - from Apple KB - [Xcode 10 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes)

Your iMac 11,2 is limited to High Sierra & is unable to run Mojave - see Everymac - [Apple iMac "Core i3" 3.06 21.5-Inch (Mid-2010) Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i3-3.06-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html)

All of which means you **can** run the current Xcode, though depending on what Apple does in macOS 10.15 you may not be able to run the next version.